# Indexing Selection problems

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data = DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4)),
    index=['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'Utah', 'New York'],
    columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
```

outputs:

```
>>> data
           one  two  three  four
Ohio        0    1      2     3
Colorado    4    5      6     7
Utah        8    9     10    11
New York   12   13     14    15
```

I now want to:

1. filter this data frame and only output rows where ['three'] > 5
2. output only the 1st 3 rows... so ignore the final one [:2]

I write this:

```
data.iloc[data['three']>5, [:2]]
```

and get this error:

```
    >>> data.iloc[data['three']>5, [:2]]
         File "<stdin>", line 1
         data.iloc[data['three']>5, [:2]]
                                     ^
```

how do I fix this??

these are my imports

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Try this:    `data[data['three']>5][:2]`

Comment: Just saw that @IoaTzimas has answered it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but what I have understood is you need Colorado and Utah in your final output. If that is the case, change the code to :

```
data[data['three']>5][:2]
```

Comment: thank you, it had been stressing me out for too long!